# hmr Invalidate React Vite

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en React utlizando Vite con typeScript + swc, y me aparece este error en la terminal:
"[vite] hmr invalidate /src/context/Context.tsx Could not Fast Refresh. Learn more at [https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react-swc#consistent-components-exports"](https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react-swc#consistent-components-exports%22)
donde mi codigo dentro de Context.tsx es el siguiente:

```
export const PricesContext = createContext<Context>({} as Context)
export function PricesProvider({children}:{children:ReactNode}){
const { filteredProducts, setFitler, minMaxPrice } = UseFilter()

return(
 <PricesContext.Provider 
  value={{filteredProducts,setFitler,minMaxPrice}}>
    {children}
 </PricesContext.Provider>
 )
 }
```